# Where can I find the standalone .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack Offline Installer?

Tags: .net, hyperlink, installation, offline

Usually the Setups are 60MB+ 
Official Site seams to be broken

- https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks
- https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all

I can get there only Lagnuage Pack for example-> NDP472-DevPack-DEU.exe
and that are ~15MB

Any ideas? Does it work only with specific localisation? I will give a shot for USA proxy (currently I am in Germany).

Greetings to Microsoft! Do you read this... it's 2 day old and download Link even now seams to be broken ;(

Comment: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=863261&clcid=0x409

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me also with Proxy :)